# Highlight in Lucene with certain numbers of surrounding words

Tags: lucene, highlight

I want to make a highlight in Lucene which beside the highlighted word it also returns its context which consists of a certain number of words surrounding the searched term. For example, if the content of a document is `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`, the searched word is `fox` and the desired number of surrounding words is 2, the result should look like this `quick brown <B> fox </B> jumps over`

Comment: See Lucene's [Highlighter API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html).

Comment: As I can see, Lucene's Highlighter API only provides options for the size of the returned fragment measured in number of characters and not in number of words as desired: `setMaxDocCharsToAnalyze(int maxDocCharsToAnalyze) `.

Comment: The Fragmenter handles that, you can change it, implement your own, or use a different Highlighter, such as PostingsHighlighter.